# awk to calculate average of field in multiple text files and merge into one

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to calculate the average of `$2` in multiple test files in a directory and merge the output in one `tab-delimeted` output file.  The output file is two fields, in which `$1` is the file name that has been extracted by `pref`, and `$2" is the calculated average with one decimal, rounded up. There is also a header in the output`Sample`in`$1`and`Percent`in`$2`. The below seems close but I am missing a few things (adding the header to the output, merging into one tab-delimeted file, and rounding to 3 decimal places), that I do not know how to do yet and not getting the desired output.  Thank you :).

**123_base.txt**

```
AASS     99.81
ABAT     100.00
ABCA10   0.0
```

**456_base.txt**

```
ABL2     97.81
ABO  100.00
ACACA    99.82
```

**desired output** (tab-delimeted)

```
Sample Percent
123    66.6
456    99.2
```

**Bash**

```
for f in /home/cmccabe/Desktop/20x/percent/*.txt ; do
 bname=$(basename $f)
 pref=${bname%%_base_*.txt}
 awk -v OFS='\t' '{ sum += $2 } END { if (NR > 0) print sum / NR }' $f /home/cmccabe/Desktop/NGS/bed/bedtools/IDP_total_target_length_by_panel/IDP_unix_trim_total_target_length.bed > /home/cmccabe/Desktop/20x/coverage/${pref}_average.txt
done
```

Comment: how about a perl solution?

Comment: That would be ok.  Thank you :).

Comment: @glenn jackman can all 100 `.txt` files in a directory (`/home/cmccabe/Desktop/20x/percent/*.txt`) be used at one time, without having to reference each?  Thank you :).

Comment: yup.. that would get expanded by shell and awk would see all the files.. however since you are giving full path, getting pref would have to be modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In awk. Notice `printf "%3.3s"` to truncate the filename after 3rd char:

```
$ cat ave.awk
BEGIN {print "Sample", "Percent"}                      # header
BEGINFILE {s=c=0}                                      # at the start of every file reset
{s+=$2; c++}                                           # sum and count hits
ENDFILE{if(c>0) printf "%3.3s%s%.1f\n", FILENAME, OFS, s/c} 
                                                       # above output if more than 0 lines
```

Run it:

```
$ touch empty_base.txt                                 # test for division by zero
$ awk -f ave.awk 123_base.txt 123_base.txt empty_base.txt
Sample Percent
123 66.6
456 99.2
```

Comment: Good idea to guard against division by zero.

Answer (score 5):

This one uses GNU awk, which provides handy `BEGINFILE` and `ENDFILE` events:

```
gawk '
    BEGIN {print "Sample\tPercent"}
    BEGINFILE {sample = FILENAME; sub(/_.*/,"",sample); sum = n = 0}
    {sum += $2; n++}
    ENDFILE {printf "%s\t%.1f\n", sample, sum/n}
' 123_base.txt 456_base.txt
```

If you're giving a pattern with the directory attached, I'd get the sample name like this:

```
match(FILENAME, /^.*\/([^_]+)/, m); sample = m[1]
```

and then, yes this is OK: `gawk '...' /path/to/*_base.txt`

And to steal against division by zero, inspired by James Brown's answer:

```
ENDFILE {printf "%s\t%.1f\n", sample, n==0 ? 0 : sum/n}
```

Answer (score 3):

with `perl`

```
$ perl -ane '
BEGIN{ print "Sample\tPercent\n" }
$c++; $sum += $F[1];
if(eof)
{
    ($pref) = $ARGV=~/(.*)_base/;
    printf "%s\t%.1f\n", $pref, $sum/$c;
    $c = 0; $sum = 0;
}' 123_base.txt 456_base.txt
Sample  Percent
123 66.6
456 99.2
```

- print header using `BEGIN` block
- `-a` option would split input line on spaces and save to `@F` array
- For each line, increment counter and add to sum variable
- If end of file `eof` is detected, print in required format
- `$ARGV` contains current filename being read

If full path of filename is passed but only filename should be used to get `pref`, then use this line instead

```
($pref) = $ARGV=~/.*\/\K(.*)_base/;
```

Comment: You have forgotten to use `-n`. If you add `-l`, you don't need to add `\n` to your print statements.

Comment: @glennjackman, `-a` would invoke `-n` as well... `-l` doesn't seem to add `\n` with printf hence I didn't use :)

Comment: I did not know that about `-a`

Comment: also, `-F` (to specify field separator other than spaces) would invoke `-a` and `-n` - http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches

Comment: Hmm, too implicit for me. I prefer my options spelled out: `perl -lane '...'`

Comment: @glennjackman looks like the implicit setting is version dependent as well... gonna modify my answer to use explicit options... thanks

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{f=FILENAME;sub(/_.*/,"",f); 
                    a[f]+=$2; c[f]++} 
                END{print "Sample","Percent"; 
                    for(k in a) print k, sprintf("%.1f",a[k]/c[k])}' {123,456}_base.txt

Sample Percent
456 99.2
123 66.6
```